# AWS ECS: Severe bug in ECS Service Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-ecs

Trying to create an ECS service using cloudformation via the following manifest that has the appropriate imports

```
 UIService:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Service
        Properties:
          Cluster: !ImportValue ECSClusterName
          DesiredCount: 1
          LaunchType: EC2
          LoadBalancers:
            - ContainerName: !ImportValue UIContainerName
              ContainerPort: '80'
              TargetGroupArn: !ImportValue UITGArn
          ServiceName: ui-service
          ServiceRegistries:
           - RegistryArn: arn:aws:servicediscovery:eu-west-1:944094092130:service/srv-oIclu40KCKM3esez7
          TaskDefinition: !ImportValue UITaskArn
```

This fails with the following message:

> When specifying 'host' or 'bridge' for networkMode, values for 'containerName' and 'containerPort' must be specified from the task definition.

However when I add the wanted values (in the serviceregistry property where it makes me assume they are needed ?)

```
  UIService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !ImportValue ECSClusterName
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: EC2
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !ImportValue UIContainerName
          ContainerPort: '80'
          TargetGroupArn: !ImportValue UITGArn
      ServiceName: ui-service
      ServiceRegistries:
       - RegistryArn: arn:aws:servicediscovery:eu-west-1:944094092130:service/srv-oIclu40KCKM3esez7
         ContainerName: !ImportValue UIContainerName
         ContainerPort: '80'
      TaskDefinition: !ImportValue UITaskArn
```

... I get the following failure:

> Encountered unsupported property ContainerName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug from AWS, in which the cloudformation is not supporting *containerName* and *containerPort* attribute currently. Here is the official [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ServiceRegistry.html) for *ServiceRegistry*, and here is the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/aws-cloudformation-coverage-updates-for-amazon-api-gateway--amaz/) for cloudformation. If I am not wrong, when service discovery was released, it only supported *awsvpc* networking mode and *bridge/host* was added later. It explains why we are having such discrepancy.

For the time being, you can create the basic ECS cloudformation, and update accordingly using CLI/API/SDK, or you can wait for sometimes so that AWS team will add support for the same.

Updated: As per this [new feature](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/aws-cloudformation-coverage-updates-for-amazon-api-gateway--amaz/) (introduced on 24 Sep 2018), now you can specify the `containerName` and `containerPort` in the [Service Registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-serviceregistry.html).

Answer (score 1):

As per latest [feature](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/aws-cloudformation-coverage-updates-for-amazon-api-gateway--amaz/) (introduced today), now you can specific the containerName and containerPort in [ServiceRegistry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-serviceregistry.html).

I have quickly tested and it seems working just fine.

Comment: Probably better to edit the accepted answer with an update.