# Is it possible to specify data format conversion in AWS Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

The AWS docs makes it look as if you can specify `DataFormatConversionConfiguration` for a `AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream` in cloudformation, but is not documentation on where the property is supposed to go. Tried adding it under `Properties`, `ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration`, `ProcessingConfiguration`, and one of the `Processors`. Each time, CF complains with-

> The following resource(s) failed to update: [EventFirehose].
>   12:24:32 UTC-0500
>
> UPDATE_FAILED AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream    EventFirehose   Encountered unsupported property DataFormatConversionConfiguration

There own docs say-

> If you want Kinesis Data Firehose to convert the format of your input data from JSON to Parquet or ORC, specify the optional DataFormatConversionConfiguration element in ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration or in ExtendedS3DestinationUpdate.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per SDK [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration.html), it should be inside `ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration` or `ExtendedS3DestinationUpdate`. However, the cloudformation is currently **NOT** supporting this property as per this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-extendeds3destinationconfiguration.html). This is a very common discrepancy between cloudformation and other AWS services. One similar issue is mentioned here [AWS ECS: Severe bug in ECS Service Cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270322/aws-ecs-severe-bug-in-ecs-service-cloudformation-template/52488311#52488311) (which got resolved recently).

For the time being, you can update via SDK or wait for some time for cloudformation to catch up.

> If you want Kinesis Data Firehose to convert the format of your input data from JSON to Parquet or ORC, specify the optional DataFormatConversionConfiguration element in ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration or in ExtendedS3DestinationUpdate

**Edit**

As of June 2019, the `DataFormatConversionConfiguration` property is in available in CloudFormation. See change log: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html

Comment: Thank you for affirming. I expected as much after an hour of searching. Very frustrating

Comment: You are welcome. Now, if I come across to similar issue, I just merely compare docs between sdk and cloudformation, it did save me a lot of time :)

Comment: I don't suppose anyone has a working example of this? I've been struggling all day to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

Here how I have solved this task. Firehose stream writes data to S3 bucket in parquet format:

```yaml
LogsCollectionDatabase:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Database
  Properties:
    DatabaseInput:
      Description: Database for Kinesis Analytics
      Name: !Ref DatabaseName
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId

LogsCollectionTable:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Table
  DependsOn: LogsCollectionDatabase
  Properties:
    DatabaseName: !Ref LogsCollectionDatabase
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    TableInput:
      Name: serverlogs
      Description: Table for storing logs from kinesis
      TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
      StorageDescriptor:
        Columns:
          - Type: string
            Name: col1
          - Type: string
            Name: col2
        Location: !Sub s3://${DestinationBucketName}/${DestinationBucketPrefix}
        InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
        OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
        SerdeInfo:
          SerializationLibrary: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe

KinesisFirehoseDeliveryStream:
  Type: AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
  DependsOn: FirehoseDeliveryIAMPolicy
  Properties:
    DeliveryStreamName: !Ref RegionalStreamName
    DeliveryStreamType: DirectPut
    ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration:
      BucketARN: !Ref DestinationBucketArn
      Prefix: !Ref DestinationBucketPrefix
      BufferingHints:
        IntervalInSeconds: 60
        SizeInMBs: 64
      ErrorOutputPrefix: errors/
      RoleARN: !GetAtt FirehoseDeliveryIAMRole.Arn
      DataFormatConversionConfiguration:
        Enabled: true
        InputFormatConfiguration:
          Deserializer:
            HiveJsonSerDe: {}
        OutputFormatConfiguration:
          Serializer:
            ParquetSerDe: {}
        SchemaConfiguration:
          CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
          RoleARN: !GetAtt FirehoseDeliveryIAMRole.Arn
          DatabaseName: !Ref LogsCollectionDatabase
          TableName: !Ref LogsCollectionTable
          Region: !Ref AWS::Region
          VersionId: LATEST
```

Of course, need to define IAM role & policy for FirehosStream

Comment: For the ones who needs to figure out what policies are need for the role: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-glue