# How can I update a FireHose delivery stream's DataFormatConversionConfiguration using the AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Does anyone have a working example of using `firehose.update_destination` to set an S3 destination's `DataFormatConversionConfiguration`? I'm following the guidance in [Is it possible to specify data format conversion in AWS Cloudformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523378/is-it-possible-to-specify-data-format-conversion-in-aws-cloudformation), using boto3 (the AWS Python SDK), but I've not been successful. When I include a DFCC in an `ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration` argument, it fails with the following error:

```
Exception during processing: An error occurred (InvalidArgumentException) when calling the UpdateDestination operation: RoleArn must not be null or empty
```

If I pass the original destination configuration (as returned by `describe_delivery_stream`) unchanged, the update succeeds. I can also change other config options, e.g. `BufferingHints`. The only time it fails is when `DataFormatConversionConfiguration` is non-null.

For example, passing this works:

```
{
  "RoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/MyExecutionRole",
  "BucketARN": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
  "Prefix": "databases/tables/requests/",
  "BufferingHints": {
    "SizeInMBs": 64,
    "IntervalInSeconds": 120
  },
  "CompressionFormat": "UNCOMPRESSED",
  "EncryptionConfiguration": {
    "NoEncryptionConfig": "NoEncryption"
  },
  "CloudWatchLoggingOptions": {
    "Enabled": false
  },
  "S3BackupMode": "Disabled"
}
```

but passing this fails:

```
{
  "RoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/MyExecutionRole",
  "BucketARN": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
  "Prefix": "databases/tables/requests/",
  "BufferingHints": {
    "SizeInMBs": 64,
    "IntervalInSeconds": 120
  },
  "CompressionFormat": "UNCOMPRESSED",
  "EncryptionConfiguration": {
    "NoEncryptionConfig": "NoEncryption"
  },
  "CloudWatchLoggingOptions": {
    "Enabled": false
  },
  "S3BackupMode": "Disabled",
  "DataFormatConversionConfiguration": {
    "InputFormatConfiguration": {
      "Deserializer": {
        "OpenXJsonSerDe": {
        }
      }
    },
    "SchemaConfiguration": {
      "TableName": "requests",
      "DatabaseName": "mydb"
    },
    "OutputFormatConfiguration": {
      "Serializer": {
        "OrcSerDe": {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only difference is the `DataFormatConversionConfiguration` element.

Am I overlooking something obvious? Perhaps the `DFCC` element is malformed? I've not been able to find any working examples, so I'm going purely from documentation.

I'm also rather surprised by the use of `RoleARN` and `BucketARN` in the input element, vs the usual convention of `RoleArn` and `BucketArn`, but not sure if it's germane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, your `DataFormatConversionConfiguration` is malformed.

Perhaps confusingly I think the `RoleArn` it's complaining about being missing is `DataFormatConversionConfiguration.SchemaConfiguration.RoleARN`.

I'm not going to copy it all here, but I find looking at the service documentation is the best way to find deeper information about the types used by the SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_DataFormatConversionConfiguration.html

Comment: Thanks! And, yes, I've often figured out some obscure CFm error by comparing the SDK documentation, the base API reference, and the CLI documentation and triangulating; hadn't done that in this case.

Of course, looking at API docs gets you only so far, since – inexplicably, maddeningly – CFn doesn't always support all the properties defined for the API.

Comment: Yeah, CFn often lags behind (a fact not helped by AWS' spotty docs!). I guess because it's maintained by a different team- which seems like a weird choice to me- but who am I to argue with AWS' success! Good luck!