# specify tag immutability in AWS ECR using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ecr

Is it possible to specify image tag immutability in an AWS ECR CloudFormation template?

Image tag immutability is an option at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/create-repository.html but I don't see any obvious way to do it at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecr-repository.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the common issue with Cloudformation, which is always lagged behind. You might need to wait for some time util CF is supported this feature. Currently, I just run the aws cli to update this tag immutability (as well as image scanning upon pushing)

Here is one similar issue raised before.

[Is it possible to specify data format conversion in AWS Cloudformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523378/is-it-possible-to-specify-data-format-conversion-in-aws-cloudformation/52527021#52527021)